# Command line R not recognizing two keys

Tags: r, cmd, rgui

New to R, but never have seen anything similar in any other context or application.

Recently downloaded R 3.3.3 "Another Canoe" into a Windows 10 machine.

When in "command line R" (i.e., just invoking the command "r" at the Windows command line), the R interpreter doesn't recognize either my forward slash (/) key nor my Enter key **on the numeric keypad portion of the keyboard**. All other keys in the numeric keypad section operate as they should. Also, both of those keys (forward slash, enter) **in the main qwerty part of the keyboard** work fine in command line R.

But in the Rgui that ships with R, both of those keys work just fine.

Don't think it's the keyboard, as (a) those keys work with every other application (including Rgui, as mentioned), and (b) I tried a different keyboard (one with a separate numeric keypad) and had identical results in command line R.

Update edit: As an experiment I plugged one of those standalone numeric keypads into a USB port, and same results: Command-line R would accept every key except " / " and "Enter".

Any thoughts?

Comment: The slashes are actually two different keys. If you test on a site like http://keycode.info/ you'll see that they map to "forward slash" and "divide" so they are not the same. The Windows console interface didn't map them to the same behavior. I think the different enter keys map to different enter/return values as well. So basically they keys aren't identical, and the R command line treats them differently while other programs map them to the same key.

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one keyboard language installed and accidentally set the keyboard to a different layout? I have ENG and ESP installed and occasionally I hit the key sequence to switch without knowing.

Comment: Thanks to both. I did test on the keycode site and saw that indeed, the numeric keypad forward slash and the fwd slash of the regular qwerty keyboard do map to different functions or operations. The two Enter keys seemed the same to keycode.info, but nevertheless I think MrFlick's suggestion puts me on the right trail. Lit, I'll have a look at the keyboard language configuration as well.